# Show Diff shortcut in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

How can i assign a key shortcut for the Show Diff action (in Version Control panel) shown in the picture in WebStorm? In IDEA it is assignable and by default is CMD+D. Not being able to assign this is driving me nuts.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try a workaround from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139526#comment=27-981608 - does it help?

Comment: Yes it did help, thank you very much. The important thing here was restart the IDE. I did try it before but it didn't work since i didn't restart.